# where does the "get" command in PSFTP (PuTTY) save the file?

Tags: ssh, putty, sftp, psftp

I'm used to running ssh on a Unix command-line and am working for the first time with PuTTY on Windows.  When I type

```
get file.txt
```

on the PSFTP command line, where does file.txt go?  PSFTP returned:

```
remote:/somedirectories/file.txt => local:file.txt
```

but I can't find the file locally.

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It saves it in the local working directory.  You can see the local working directory by typing:

```
lpwd
```

You can change the local working directory using:

```
lcd \path\to\new\dir
```

Comment: you are a life saver... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it the hard way try this...

```
defstr zz$, a7$, b7$
defint n7n
n7n=0


a7$="c:\documents\mycom\myshi\dir\fir\tre\somefile.bas"'filepath

for n= 0 to len(a7$)
  zz$=mid$(a7$, n, 1)
  if zz$="\" then 
    n7n=n7n+1
  end if
next n

for n=1 to n7n
  b7$ = field$(a7$, "\", n) & chr$(92)
  riched1.addstrings "lcd " & b7$
  print b7$
next n
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0):

```
defstr zz$, a7$, b7$
defint n7n
n7n=0


a7$="c:\documents\mycom\myshi\dir\fir\tre\somefile.bas"'filepath
for n= 0 to len(a7$)
  zz$=mid$(a7$, n, 1)
  if zz$="\" then 
    n7n=n7n+1
  end if
next n

for n=1 to n7n
  b7$ = field$(a7$, "\", n) & chr$(92)
  stores in dum$
  riched1.addstrings "lcd " & b7$
  print b7$
next n
```

Comment: You should delete this, you posted twice instead of editing...

Answer (score 0):

You can also right click `PSFTP` icon.

Then go to properties, set the path to a directory you prefer at local PC.

e.g. `C:\download\psftp\`